# How to map over generator in parallel using ray?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ray

I'd like to process elements from a very large generator. However, ray seems to convert the generator into a list before the mapping can start. There is a side constraint that the function I'd like to map over the values has an expensive initialization, therefore I created a class for it. The order of the output does not matter.

```py
import time
import ray

@ray.remote
class MyWorker:
    def __init__(self):
        time.sleep(5)  # expensive init

    def work(self, d):
        return d

ray.init()
pool = ray.util.ActorPool([MyWorker.remote() for _ in range(8)])
many_values = (d for d in range(10 ** 10))
for output in pool.map_unordered(lambda a, v: a.work.remote(v), many_values):
    print(output)
ray.shutdown()
```

How do you assign values from the generator to workers such that utilization is high?

Comment: You *are* mapping in parallel, but `map` and `map_unordered` are documented as requiring lists as arguments. You might want to iterate over the generator yourself and use `pool.submit` instead to "call" the function. While doing that, you can make calls to `pool.get_next_unordered` to retrieve complete results.

Comment: That sounds like it might work. Can you write an answer for this?